# Bootstrap's SelectPicker Issue with Google Map

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

I want to set selected Option in Select Picker,I have the following code which is working properly.

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control input-sm selectpicker" id="area_location_id">
    <option value="" selected="">Select</option>
    <option value="17">Al Barsha</option>
    <option value="82">Al Furjan</option>
    <option value="4924">Al Garhoud</option>
    <option value="5787">Al Jadaf</option>
    <option value="5684">Al Mamzar</option>
    <option value="123">Dubai Marina</option>
</select>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js">    </script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap-select.js"></script> 
 <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script> 
<script src="js/dropzone.js"></script> 
<script src="plugin/sumernote/summernote.min.js"></script>
```

JQuery:

```
var userToSearchFor = " Marina";

$("#area_location_id").find("option:contains('" + userToSearchFor + "')").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
});

$('#area_location_id').selectpicker('val', userToSearchFor);
$('#area_location_id').selectpicker('refresh');
```

The above code is working and 'Dubai Marina' is selected. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h7ct7tsk/)

**What I Want:**

Now I want to use this code in Google Maps code,when user select any location,it should select.

Here is my code which is not working

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {

    var userToSearchFor = " Marina";
    $("#area_location_id").find("option:contains('" + userToSearchFor + "')").each(function () {
        $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
    });
    $('#area_location_id').selectpicker('val', userToSearchFor);
    $('#area_location_id').selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

Now the same code is not working here.Although control comes here.

UPDATED: When i include this file then only my code is not working

```
bootstrap-select.js
```

Any Help?

Comment: *when user select any location, it should select.* The listener you have added will be triggered on map click.

Comment: Yes, when i click on map,it do not select 'Dubai Marina'...means the same coding is not working..althogh i can get click event

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why this would not work.

```
function initialize() {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.2, 6.17);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {

        var userToSearchFor = " Marina";
        $("#area_location_id").find("option:contains('" + userToSearchFor + "')").each(function () {
            $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
        });
        $('#area_location_id').selectpicker('val', userToSearchFor);
        $('#area_location_id').selectpicker('refresh');
    });
}

initialize();
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/go6qcfau/)</kbd>

Comment: When i include this file then it do not work  'bootstrap-select.js'

Comment: Where do you include it? How? Where is that part of your code?

Comment: I am creating bootstrap dropdown not simple one,that is why i need to include this file...'http://mallscombined.com/gistlerdemo/js/bootstrap-select.js'

Comment: Can you not read my comment? **Where** and **How** did you include this file? [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)! Update your question with the information since this is obviously the most important part of it.

Comment: No Error,but it do not work.When i remove this link then it is working..but that also removes bootstrap

Comment: Live link to reproduce the issue. I can't tell from what you provided.